# error: Expected member name or constructor call after type name

Tags: swift

collectionViewのカスタムセルにボタンを一つ配置しようとコードを書いたのですが、ビルドする前にタイトルのようなエラーが出てしまいます。
どなたか解決法をご教示ください
よろしくおねがいします。

ビューコントローラー；

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupSubviews()
        self.autolayoutSubviews()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func setupSubviews() {
        let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(300.0, 100.0)

        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        self.collectionView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.collectionView!.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView!.delegate = self
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(ButtonCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ButtonCell")　//ここでエラー
        self.collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView!)
    }

    func autolayoutSubviews() {
        self.collectionView!.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor).active = true
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ButtonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ButtonCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        return cell

    }
}
```

サブクラス；

```
import UIKit

class ButtonCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 50));

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.setupSubviews()
        self.autolayoutSubviews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.setupSubviews()
        self.autolayoutSubviews()
    }



    func setupSubviews() {

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor();
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
        button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("btn_click:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside);
        button.setTitle("Tap Me", forState: UIControlState.Normal);
        self.addSubview(button);

    }

    func autolayoutSubviews() {

    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

    }
}
```

Comment: エラーが出たのは、どちらのコードの何行目なのですか？

Comment: コード整形しないと気づかなかったと思いますが、「//ここでエラー」というコメントはありますね。エラーのある前の行など分かりやすい箇所にあったほうがよいかもですね。

Comment: @moriyan さん、このサイトは質問者自身の問題の解決だけでなく、知識の集積も目的としていますので、余程の事がないかぎり、問題が解決しても質問の削除は必要はありません。削除する必要があるならば、理由を説明して下さい。例えば「質問の内容に著作権侵害があった」などです。

Comment: @Shintaro さん、編集内容を取り消して戻す場合は、再度編集するのではなく「ロールバック」という操作がよいと思います。（私もあまり解っていないので、これが利用出来ない事情があったらすいません）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`registerClass(_: forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)`の第一引数に渡すものは、`AnyClass?`です。

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(ButtonCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ButtonCell")
```

クラスを値として渡すには、クラス名の後に`.self`を使います。

Swift の Language Reference の [Types - Metatype Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html) の項を参照してみてください。

Comment: おかげでできました。感謝いたします。